# VHDL coding in Isim Wave Window

Tags: vhdl

In the Isim wave window my internal signals and outputs appear green and as initialized but all of my inputs appear as "UU" even though they are initialized as well. I am simply trying to add 1 whenever either of the two inputs are 1. The code synthesizes fine without warnings. 
Any ideas?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity scoreboard2 is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           T1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           T2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Output : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end scoreboard2;

architecture Behavioral of scoreboard2 is
signal output_temp: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal score1,score2: unsigned(1 downto 0) := "00";
signal score3: unsigned(3 downto 0):= "0000";

begin
    proc: process(T1,T2,clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(T1 = '1') then
                score1 <= score1 + 1;
            end if;
            if(T2 = '1') then
                score2 <= score2 + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process proc;

score3 <= score1 & score2;
output_temp <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(score3);
Output <= output_temp;

end Behavioral;



LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;


ENTITY test6 IS
END test6;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test6 IS 

    COMPONENT scoreboard2
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         T1 : IN  std_logic;
         T2 : IN  std_logic;
         Output : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '1';
   signal T1 : std_logic := '1';
   signal T2 : std_logic := '1';

    --Outputs
   signal Output : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal output_temp: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal score1,score2: unsigned(1 downto 0) := "00";
    signal score3: unsigned(3 downto 0):= "0000";

   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

   uut: scoreboard2 PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          T1 => T1,
          T2 => T2,
          Output => Output
        );

   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   stim_proc: process
   begin        
        wait for 100 ns;
        T1 <= '1';
      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: You ARE simulating "test6" (the testbench) and not "scoreboard2" (the UUT), right? And check that the "uut" in test6 points to scoreboard2. Doing that, your problem does not exist here in ISIM 14.3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Isim but some simulators allow you to run a top level design with a port having unconnected inputs. It's usually synonymous with the ability to do interactive simulation (run, stop, step, force inputs, etc.).

Chapter 5 of ise_tutorial_ug695.pdf, March 1, 2011 (v13.1) says you need a test bench, i don't have all the documentation to determine whether that is enforced or not.

For a test bench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity scoreboard_tb is
end entity;

architecture test of scoreboard_tb is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal T1:      std_logic := '0';
    signal T2:      std_logic := '0';
    signal RESULT:  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin

UNDER_TEST:
    entity work.scoreboard2 
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            T1 => T1,
            T2 => T2,
            Output => RESULT
        );
CLOCK:
    process 
    begin
        if Now > 340 ns then     -- simulation stops with no signal events 
            wait;
        end if;
        clk <= not clk; 
        wait for 20 ns;      
    end process;
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 40 ns;
        T1 <= '1';
        wait for 40 ns;
        T2 <= '1';
        wait for 40 ns;
        T1 <= '0';
        T2 <= '0';
        wait for 40 ns;
        T2 <= '1';
        wait for 40 ns;
        T2 <= '0';
        T1 <= '1';
        wait for 40 ns;
        T1 <= '0';
        wait;

    end process;

end architecture;
```

ghdl produces:

[image]

for you're scoreboard2 entity/architecture pair analyzed unchanged.

Comment: he already has a testbench which looks OK (if not very thorough). My guess is simply simulating the UUT instead of the TB (since the TB has no inputs). Easily done by clicking the wrong place!

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Isim either. Probably the softwave itself didn't work well. If there is a wave editor or something similar in Isim, use it instead of a testbench. Then simulate your project again. Hope this helps:)